# alertTitle not showing in uilocalnotification banner or alert, but showing in notification center

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

So I am using an iOS9.x device and I've set the `notification.alertTitle` to my custom text.
However, when the notification arrives, for both the banner and alert types, the title still shows the product name, which I don't want.

Strange thing though is on the notification center, my custom text shows up as alertTitle, which is what I want.

Any ideas how I can set this to banner and alert types as well, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that what you want is not possible.

iOS uses the app name in banners, alerts, and on the lock screen, and the alertTitle only in the notification center.

Comment: I see. However, my observation when you say app name is that it's taking the product name instead of the bundle display name if they are different. Though I can change the name of the app (that's shown below the icon) by merely changing the bundle display name, changing the product name messes up a lot of stuff that I wanted to avoid.